# add permission and share a sharepoint online file using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I have been using powershell to programmatically manage some tedious work in SharePoint Online (SPO) 
I have been using the Cmdlets of [Powershell PnP](https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices). I have been looking for a cmdlet that will let me add/share give permission to a user so he/she can access this file located in a document library on SharePoint Online.

How can I share a SPO Document library file with edit or view permission using Powershell?

if you could please guide me in the right direction

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a PnP cmdelt `Set-PnPListItemPermission`. You can use this to share the list item with your user.

Example use:

```
Set-PnPListItemPermission -List 'Documents' -Identity 1 -User 'user@contoso.com' -AddRole 'Contribute'
```

This will provide the 'Contribute' permission to the user 'user@contoso.com' for list item (document) with id 1 in the list 'Documents'

For more examples see the [PnP Documentation](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/SetPnPListItemPermission.md) for this cmdlet.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but the Set-PnPListPermission doesn't have a -List Parameter !

Comment: Apologies, I included a typo. I meant to recommend `Set-PnPListItemPermission`. I have updated the answer above, this one should have the `-List` parameter

Comment: Awesome. Looks like I was running an outdated PnP module, update-module wasn't updating the module because it was installed manually, so I uninstalled it from add or remove programs then used the install-module *pnp* and voila :-) the new cmdlet set-pnplistitempermission showed up. Thanks again